# VBA only sort text, disregard cells with formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large sheet with ~150 columns, most of which contains formulas. When i want to sort the data that i input to the cells that do not use formulas, it messes up the entire sheet. - The input cells are not together

Currently my solution in VBA would be to copy the cells to another (hidden) sheet, sort and put it all back. I just feel that this is way too much work for a seemingly simple task. Is there a smarter way to solve this?

**EDIT**

qua @varocarbas i have tried the following code:

```
Private Sub sortInputButton_Click()
    ' This sub sorts the inpur, without messing up the references [hopefully]
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim colCount As Integer

    rowCount = countItems
    colCount = 180

    Dim inputRange As Range
    Set inputRange = Sheets("Input").Range("A3")
    Set inputRange = inputRange.Resize(rowCount, colCount)

    Dim targetRange As Range

    On Error Resume Next ' If range is nothing, throws an error - we don't want that
    Set targetRange = inputRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If targetRange.Cells.count > 0 Then
        Sheets("Input").Select
        targetRange.Select
        Call targetRange.Sort(Sheets("Input").Range("A3"), xlAscending)
    End If

End Sub
```

But this give me the error `the command you chose cannot be performed with multiple selections. Select a single range and click the command again.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SpecialCells`:

```
Dim targetRange As Range
On Error Resume Next 'In case of not finding any cell under the requested conditions.
Set targetRange = inputRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

`inputRange` includes all the cells and `targetRange` just the ones not including a formula.

UPDATE:

```
Dim targetRange As Range
On Error Resume Next ' If range is nothing, throws an error - we don't want that
Set targetRange = inputRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Call targetRange.Sort(targetRange.Cells(1, 1), xlAscending)
'targetRange.Sort targetRange.Cells(1, 1), xlAscending -> alternative not requiring "Call"
```

You don't need `On Error GoTo 0`, neither `targetRange.Cells.count` (if `targetRange` does not have cells, `On Error Resume Next` would catch it -> that's why I included this line; `SpecialCells` has this small limitation). You don't need any of the `.Select` calls you are including either. And what is presumably provoking the error in `.Sort` is `Sheets("Input").Range("A3")` which I have replaced with the first cell of `targetRange` (whatever it is).

Comment: This seemed to work at first - but i found that it only works before i enter details. Then i get this error: `the command you chose cannot be performed with multiple selections. Select a single range and click the command again.`

I have 6 cells of user entered data, and then 20x `[formula][input]` followed by a whole lot more. My point is that input and formulas are mixed.

Comment: @Kentora I am not understanding the problem. Can you please update your question with the code you tried such that I can help? This solution should work without any limitation.

Comment: @Kentora additionally I have included an error catching and thus it cannot output an error in any case (in the worst scenario it will not work).

Comment: i have now updated the question. It is not the `Specialcells` command i'm having problems with - it is the sorting itself.

Comment: @Kentora OK. There are various redundant parts in your code but it should work anyway. The problem is, most likely, provoked by Sheets("Input").Range("A3") which you use as reference for the sort, although might not be present in targetRage (might have a formula). Will update my answer right now with a code I hope you will find useful.

Comment: @Kentora There you have it. Test this code (+ understand the comments) and let me know how it goes.